# How can I route two audio sources simultaneously as inputs to Skype?

Tags: skype, audio

I am attempting to route my mic audio and system output so both can be heard through Skype.  Any ideas?

Comment: What input are you using?

Answer (score 3):

### [SoundFlower](http://cycling74.com/products/soundflower/)

This is the traditional solution, and it is free. Although I am not sure if it's compatible with Lion.

Once you have it installed, you'll need to get familiar with the Mac OS X system utility, Audio MIDI Setup, in the Utilities folder.

Comment: Yah I downloaded it a while back, but still it was hard to get all the audio right.  But I think I got it.

Comment: What operating system are you running? Snow Leopard? Lion?

Comment: Snow Leopard.  But I got everything working with SoundFlower and LineIn.  What I ended up doing is using LineIn to send my mic input to output to SoundFlower and I set my computers output in System Preferences to SoundFlower.  From SoundFlower I set the output to my speakers.  And in Skype I set my mic as SoundFlower.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an aggregated device ? I use it for outputs, but it seems that you can also configure 2 inputs. See this Apple's kb article : http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3956